# Overriding bootstrap wizard default behavior

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

http://www.panopta.com/2013/02/06/bootstrap-application-wizard

http://wstevens1.adventivedev.com/ui/js/bootstrap-wizard/bootstrap-wizard.js

I would like to override the event handler on line 484 for ALL instances of the wizard without editing the original source in bootstrap-wizard.js to get some more desirable custom behavior.

In other words I wish to override:

```
            this.el.find(".wizard-steps").on(
                    "click", "li.already-visited a.wizard-nav-link", this,
                    function(event) {
                            var index = parseInt($(event.target).data("navindex"));
                            event.data.setCard(index);
                    });
```

With my own click handler. This handler gets triggered when you select a Wizard card. I'm not savvy enough with Javascript however to know how to do this.

You may not necessarily need to know how the Wizard works, just be savvy with Javascript to be able to answer this. Anyone? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after instantiate the wizard, you can use jQuery's [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function to remove the handler, then use the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function to add your own:

```
var selector = 'li.already-visited a.wizard-nav-link';
(".wizard-steps").off('click', selector).on("click", selector, function(event) {
    //your own handler here
 });
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid doing something like that, although I may ultimately need to. Is there a way I can override the click behaviour through the el property of the Wizard object for all Wizards?

Comment: Since it is a property of `this`, it looks like `el` is specific to a wizard instance. So using that property won't let you override behavior for all wizards instantiated on the page. You could iterate through all your wizards and grab the `el` property, assuming it's publicly scoped. However, even if that did work you would still need to remove the existing event handler using `off()`.